# cacti automation tool creates devices in folders

Tags: automation, cacti

I have a problem configuring my Cacti 1.2.11.
I created an automation rule for discovered devices, it finds the proper info and creates devices and graphs for them. The only problem is that it creates device folder and device in it, instead of simply creating new device under root tree.

If someone knows how to make a rule to create the devices with no folders above, please give me a hand!

[On the left is how the graphs are created and on the right is how I want them to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVBUS.jpg)

Comment: I got the same problem with 1.2.10 version

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in my config. I shouldn't have "created tree creation criteria" item.
When created it creates leaf(=subfolder) for each device.

[Tree creation criteria is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxBpb.png)

[Tree structure as I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GxZo.png)